# Error when drawing a bitmap on a Canvas

Tags: java, android, bitmap, nullpointerexception, android-bitmap

I was trying to draw a bitmap on a `Canvas` but I got a `NullPointerException` that I don't understand. Code and error is given below:

**Code:**

```
Bitmap android_guy;
android_guy = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher),50,50, true);
canvas.drawBitmap(android_guy, width/2, 0, null);
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:702)
```

Comment: how did you get `width` value ?

Comment: that's the problem, i'am not calling this method directly then why this error?

Comment: it is not a method it is a property

Comment: i did not get the `width` value, i am just giving a random value